# Cannot login SQL Server after changing machine name

Tags: sql-server, connection, hostname, windows-event-log

After installing and setting up new machines in a domain, we decided to rename one of them which had a SQL Server instance installed. So I changed the hostname, everything went fine regarding the domain but now, the server is logging a approximatively 2 SQL Server errors every 5 minutes and I cannot connect to the instance localy or from anywhere within the domain.

Here is the error from the event log:

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed   [CLIENT: x.x.x.x]

Concerning the instance, everything is started and restarted without any extra error.

Answer (score 2):

I would say all your logins were of the form of 'computername\username' and because the computername is now different the logins don't not work anymore. If you don't have SQL-Authentication of the 'sa' password, you need to start SQL-Server in [single-user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx) in which any local administrator has access and you can fix your broken logins.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this article?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx

It might have some ideas for you.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault - [we generally expect answers here to contain more content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please consider expanding your answer so it's still useful after Microsoft breaks your link.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are login with old server name. but your server name has been changed new name is as machine and update pc name.